# reflection to pass tagName as string props to be rendered

Tags: reactjs, reflection, render, babeljs, tagname

```
class Button  extends React.Component{
    renderAnchor(){
      return <a onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.children}</a>
    }
    renderButton(){
       return <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.children}</button> 
    }
    render(){
         return (this.tagName==='a')?this.renderAnchor():this.renderButton();
    }

}
```

I have the above react-component , i want to avoid code redundancy, so , i decide to remove all render methods except the last (`render`) by replacing the tagname by `this.props.tagName`

```
     render(){
         return <{this.props.tagName} onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.children}</{this.props.tagName}>
    }
```

However, it raises an error of syntax .

How  can use reflection of tagname in react / ES7/ Babel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the tag name to a variable and use that variable as the HTML tag.

For example:

```
render(){
    const CustomTag = this.props.tagName //assign it to the variable

    return <CustomTag
      onClick={this.props.onClick}>
          {this.props.children}
      </CustomTag>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/88honb0z/